# Facebook permissions on expo-facebook not working

Tags: facebook, permissions, sdk, expo

I have ask to Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync to have permissions of pages_show_list. The login is successful but the permissions are not.

Like that:

```
facebookLogIn = async () => {
 let appID = 'XYXYXYXYXYYXYXYXYXY';
 try {
  await Facebook.initializeAsync(appID);
  const {
    type,
    token,
    expires,
    permissions,
    declinedPermissions,
  } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(appID, {
    permissions: ['public_profile', 'user_likes', 'pages_show_list'],
  });
  
  console.log(permissions);
 }
}
```

console.log (permissions) prints to console only 'public_profile', 'user_likes' but there is no 'pages_show_list'. Anyone can explain why?

Thank you

Comment: Is your app in live or dev mode, and if the former, did you get the permission approved in review already?

Comment: My app is in dev mode.This is a problem?

Comment: Should not be, if you are testing with an account that has a role in the app.

Comment: I testing with an account that has a role in the app!

Answer (score 0):

No permissions except the default are working for me either. I am in development mode.